# recurring monthly payments eWay in php

Tags: php, payment, recurring

I need  payment gateway to handle recurring monthly payments using eWay. I registered at eWay
and recieved Sandbox Customer ID, Sandbox Username, Login URL .

I use php(Codeignioter 2.1). I have link at http://www.eway.com.au/developers/api/recurring.
But I do not know how this use in my php-app. Have I to use soap library with SoapClient function ?
Please, give some example with php.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks,
but I stiill have several questions:

```
$eWay = new eWay('REAL_TIME_CVN', TRUE);  // Which must be this parameter if I use sandbox for testing ?
$eWay
 ->setCustomerID('87654321')  // Is it customer ID  I recieved when I registered at eWay site ?
 ->setCardNumber('4444333322221111') // Is this parameter and parameters below are data of User(not customer above) who pays money to Customer above ?
 ->setCardHoldersName('John Smith')
 ->setPaymentAmount(1.00)
 ->setCardExpiry('08', '09')
 ->setCVN('123')
 ->setCustomerFirstName('Firstname')
 ->setCustomerLastName('Lastname')
 ->setCustomerEmail('name@xyz.com.au')
 ->setCustomerAddress('123 Someplace Street, Somewhere ACT')
 ->setCustomerPostcode('2609')
 ->setCustomerInvoiceReference('INV120394')
 ->setCustomerInvoiceDescription('Testing')
 ->setCustomerTransactionReference('4230')
 ->setOption1('Option Number One')
 ->setOption2('Option Number Two')
 ->setOption3('Option Number Three')
 ;

$eWay->pay();  // I do not have to pay, but I have to verify if payment is made monthly. Which menthod have I to use?
```

---

in eWay class I found definition of loadPaymentResponse method :

```
public function loadPaymentResponse($response_string)
{
    $response = simplexml_load_string($response_string);

    $this->transactionError = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnError'};
    $this->transactionStatus = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnStatus'};
    $this->transactionNumber = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnNumber'};
    $this->transactionReference = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnReference'};
    $this->transactionAmount = (string) $response->{'ewayReturnAmount'};
    $this->transactionAuthNumber = (string) $response->{'ewayAuthCode'};
    $this->transactionOption1 = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnOption1'};
    $this->transactionOption2 = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnOption2'};
    $this->transactionOption3 = (string) $response->{'ewayTrxnOption3'};
    $this->transactionBeagleScore = (string) $response->{'ewayBeagleScore'};

    if(preg_match('/^\d{2}/', $this->transactionError, $code))
    {
        $this->responseCode = $code[0];
    }
}
```

But what is $response_string parameter?

Comment: eWAY has two PHP samples available in our Partner portal for recurring payments. One sample is for the XML version of recurring, and the second is for the web service version which is the preferred and more widely deployed API integration. The Web Service sample is built around NuSOAP and the libraries are included in the sample code as well. You can download the samples from our partner portal and if you have any questions please feel free to email support@eway.com.au or visit www.eway.com.au and initiate a live chat session with our technical support team.